# SignalR.RabbitMq scaleout issue

Tags: signalr, rabbitmq

I have a SignalrHub hosted in IIS in two servers which are loadbalanced. I used backplane rabbitmq. I had setup rabbitmq server on Server1 and on startup class registering with rabbitmq backplane pointing to the Server1 IP. Also as given in example (https://github.com/mdevilliers/SignalR.RabbitMq) I am trying to raise the message from server  on every 10 sec to all clients. The issue is, when I run only one client which is connceted to Server 1, the client is started receiving messages from Server 2 also though its not connected physically with Server 2.

But from what I understand, if Client 1 is connected with Server 1 and Client 2 connected with Server 2, when message is sent from Server 1, it will reach to server 2 and those who are connected with Server 2 will receive the Server 1's message. But in my case when there is only one client connected with Server 1, it started receiveing from Server 2 also.

But when I tried the sample given in project (https://github.com/mdevilliers/SignalR.RabbitMq/tree/master/SignalR.RabbitMQ.Example) the same case by running a timer to send message to clients, using IIS Express running on two differnt Ports, this issue not there. I mean client1 receives only from Server 1 , not from Server 2 (though its up and running).

Let me know if anything is wrong here .

thanks

Comment: Did you ever fix this?